# Intuitionistic logic's book to self study...

Tags: logic, self-learning, book-recommendation, constructive-mathematics, intuitionistic-logic

I want to study intuitionistic logic by myself?

Can you give some recommendations for the different levels (undergraduate and graduate)?

Comment: Are you already familiar with classical logic?

Comment: I have read A concise introduction to mathematical logic (Wolfgang Rautenberg).

Comment: [Van Dalen's textbook](https://books.google.it/books?id=ZWbsCAAAQBAJ&pg=PA157) has a chapter dedicated to it.

Comment: Maybe the following articles can help: https://plato.stanford.edu/search/r?entry=/entries/mathematics-constructive/&page=1&total_hits=938&pagesize=10&archive=None&rank=0&query=constructive%20mathematics https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism

Comment: I learned constructive mathematics from Ishihara Hajime's presentation materials. You may find it with some googling.